# Continuously animating border color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, border

I have some code to continuously animate the border color of a div between 3 colors using jQuery.  The problem is, rather than fade directly between red, green, and blue, the border disappears momentarily between each color transition.  Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m2f3qbo/) to see what I mean.

My jQuery code is below.  Does anyone see where I went wrong which is causing the border to disappear between animations, rather than having a smooth transition between colors like I want to have?  Any help is appreciated.

Edit:  I'm looking for a jQuery solution, not a CSS solution using transition effects.

```
animateBorder();
  function animateBorder() {
     $("#myDiv").animate({
     borderColor: "red"
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    complete: function () {
        $("#myDiv").animate({
            borderColor: "green"
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            complete: function () {
                $("#myDiv").animate({
                    borderColor: "blue"
                }, {
                    duration: 5000,
                    complete: function () {
                        animateBorder();
                    }
                });
              }
          });
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: `border` does not appear to "disappear" at http://jsfiddle.net/6m2f3qbo/ ?

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  I just noticed that it works as intended in Chrome, but in IE and FF the border disappears just before the new color fades in.

Comment: Yes. Will try ff. fwiw, `js` at OP could be shortened to eliminate duplicate `complete` function calls

Comment: Any reason for using outdated jQuery 1.5 in your demo?

Comment: @Roko - yes, I'm using some outdated plugins on the same page that won't work with newer versions of jQuery.   Edit:  The code doesn't seem to work at all when I change to a newer version of jQuery.

Comment: @guest271314 - I suppose I could do it like this  which would eliminate a lot of code, but it still does not work right in FF or IE.  Once again, Chrome looks fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/dga0kwxq/

Comment: Thanks - that does indeed get FF working, but IE9 doesn't support transitions and I need it to work in IE unfortunately :(

Comment: @JohnO Try adding `transition:border-color 1000ms` http://jsfiddle.net/6m2f3qbo/8/

Comment: @JohnO Try adding `$.fx.interval = 100` before `changeBorder` , animation called http://jsfiddle.net/6m2f3qbo/9/

Comment: @guest271314 Thangs again, it works in FF and Chrome now, but still the same in IE9 unfortunately.  I may have to try a different approach, using classes and jQuery to animate them in.  Though I'm not quite sure how to have the colors gradually fade from one to the next instead of an instant change.

Comment: @JohnO `-moz-transition:` not apply transition effect at ie ?

Comment: No, unfortunately IE9 and lower don't support CSS transitions which is why I was looking for a jQuery solution.  Here's a reference:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions